# VB.net (2010) Click-through on all controls

Tags: vb.net, click, tabpage

I'm having a application with quite a few tabpages. One function of my program is that if the user leaves the application for more than 3 minutes, I display the main tabpage where the most relevant information is shown (this is done by a timer called "back_to_main_tab"). So far so good. However in a few tabpages you can enter text and "take a pause" for more than these 3 minutes, and if that happens, the user is taken back to the main tab, without his/her consent, erasing his/her entered text.

I realize that this could be solved by enabling/disabling the back_to_main_tab-timer at strategic places, but I would like to solve it by resetting the timer each time a click is registered in the application regardless of what is is clicked. The reason for this is that the problem isn't unique for a certain tabpage, so I would like to have a "all-purpose"-fix for all tabpages.

Is this possible?

Thanks in advance

Jonas

Answer (score 0):

You can write an Event Handler for each element where user can write.

For example

```
Private Sub TextBox1_KeyDown(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.KeyEventArgs) Handles TextBox1.KeyDown
    'Reset timer
End Sub
```

(and you could try KeyUp or KeyPress too).

So you can reset timer each time the user write something somewhere.
Btw if the 3mins pass (after last KeyPress), the back_to_main_tab erase all.

**EDIT**
Ok so you could make one function to Manage the CLICK event. And attach the function to all items form.
To attacch an event handler to alla element you could try something like this

```
   Private Sub AddGenericEventHandler()
        For Each Ctrl As Item In Form.Items
               AddHandler Ctrl.Click, AddressOf MyClickHandler
        Next
   End Sub
```

And write the function that reset your timer

```
 Public Sub MyClickHandler(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs)
  'Timer Reset
  End Sub
```

This is an Idea. You have to write correctly the FOR EACH to catch all form items do you need.

Comment: Since the application is used primarily with a touch-screen (which I failed to mention, my bad), I'd like to catch all click's done to the application regardless of what control is clicked, and regardless of which tabpage is in use at the moment.

My idea was to write something generic that catches these clicks regardless of where they take place, in one place in the application, not every element where a user can write. (There would simply be too much duplicated code.)
This "one place" would be somewhere within the main form where all tabpages reside, I just don't know where.

Comment: I've edited my post to suggest you another approach to do only one function to handle all "click" in your form. Let me know

Comment: Ah, the "loop-through-all-controls"-method could be the answer I'm looking for, atleast that's a better idea than what I've come up with so far.
Think I'll go with that approach. Thanks a bunch mate.

Comment: Turns out I'm not able to catch all the click-events of a random control in my program by the use of MyClickHandler, just a few, but it seems this is the way to go. If I had enough rep I'd bump your rep GMazzacua.  :-)

Comment: Nice to hear that! If you need help we are here. Have a nice day